# How to repair excel after ComObject Release in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

After I've executed the following code:

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
            oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = false;
            oXL.IgnoreRemoteRequests = true;
            oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Workbook oWB;
            oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

            Sheets excelSheets = oWB.Worksheets;
            string currentSheet = "PC_HW_Info";
            Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

            string columnRange;
            int rowsNumber = 2;

            Range PC_User;
            PC_User = excelWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "A2");
            while ((PC_User.Value2) != null)
            {
                ++rowsNumber;
                columnRange = "A" + rowsNumber;
                PC_User = excelWorksheet.get_Range(columnRange, columnRange);
            }
            PC_User.Value2 = "aaaa";

            oXL.UserControl = false;
            oWB.SaveAs("valid path to my file", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            oWB.Close();
            oXL.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelSheets);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet);
```

my Excel is somehow corrupted and even after restart it does not come back on his initial working state. Now I cannot open worksheets directly, I have to use Open -> Browse to access a worksheet.

On the first run, when I've opened the worksheet that I've manipulated a "recovered" version of my original document appeared to be restored, I've restored it but since then I can't use Excel like before.

Any thoughts please? What am I doing wrong on the ReleaseComObject? How should I close the excel application right?

LE:
If I comment all the final lines where I close and release the objects it is working correctly.

Comment: What file format are you saving the file as in your Interop..? are you saving it as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV` ? are you saving to a valid filePath + file name..?

Comment: The file extension is .xlsx and I save it to a valid location. I can see the generated file after the execution. But I've discovered something new. Please check my update.

Comment: If you are working with a xlsx file why are you using the Com version of the Excel interop at all? You should be using the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) which is the Microsoft recommenced way to interop with office files in the xlsx format.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Scott, I did not know about that nugget recommendation and I've used a common approach with Interop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = false;
        oXL.IgnoreRemoteRequests = true;
        oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Workbook oWB;
        Workbooks wbs = oXL.Workbooks; //Never use two dots, since the middle one needs free as well
        oWB = wbs.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbs);

        Sheets excelSheets = oWB.Worksheets;
        string currentSheet = "PC_HW_Info";
        Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

        string columnRange;
        int rowsNumber = 2;

        Range PC_User;
        PC_User = excelWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "A2"); // Need to free
        while ((PC_User.Value2) != null)
        {
            ++rowsNumber;
            columnRange = "A" + rowsNumber;

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(PC_User);
            PC_User = excelWorksheet.get_Range(columnRange, columnRange);
        }
        PC_User.Value2 = "aaaa";
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(PC_User);


        oXL.UserControl = false;
        oWB.SaveAs("valid path to my file", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        oWB.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelSheets);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);

        oXL.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
```

You forgot to free Range and workbooks objects. You also got the free ordering wrong (although I don't think it will have an effect, just to be safe)

By not freeing all objects you will leave a ghost excel process in the background. Try killing those and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: I've used your rearranged code and also added Marshal.ReleaseComObject(PC_User); after oWB.Close(); but it stills blocks Excel afterwards. I found a fix to return to the initial Excel state: Options - > Advanced -> Uncheck Ignore other app that use Dynamic Data Exchange and now if I open my generated file it has correct data. The only problem is that I don't close it properly.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed a couple of more things that I've initially missed from your code, I'll return to the project.

Comment: It behaves in the same way. The output file is being generated but when I try to open it, the worksheet does not pop up. I have to do the trick that I've explained above to make it visible and it contains the correct data. But thank you for the valuable information that you provided about the two dots rule and the object release order.

Comment: @bvg do you see an excel process staying in task manager? if not then it means you have successfully released all the objects and excel quit happily. If not then there is probably more com objects somewhere you forgot to free

Comment: No Excel process present in Task Manager, Steve. When I've commented the last release lines I did have 8 or so, indeed. I've ended the tasks, run the program with your version of code and I have 0 now.

Comment: But I don't understand. Why is it all working properly if I do not close/release anything?

Comment: @bvg COM object world is like a mystery even MS can't explain. VS used to be built using COM objects and even MS team found it too annoying/too many weird behaviors that they abandoned the entire code base and started over fresh

Comment: In your form, If I comment quit and close lines it works like a charm, but of course, it leaves a process behind every time. So you propose to use DocumentFormat.OpenXml nugget remembered by Scott above, in the comments too?

Comment: @bvg yes for sure. Whenever possible I will avoid COM objects :)

Comment: I will mark your answer as right, 'cause I have no reason to reject it. As you said, there are no leftover processes with your approach and I've learned a couple of things from your post, so thank you for your time, Steve!